Invoke-WebRequest returns 200 for a non-existent URL
I'm trying to come up with a (simple and quick) method in PowerShell to determine if a resource (e.g. a file) represented by a URL exists or not.
I've read the different posts on this, but:
When I use
Invoke-WebRequest "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/blah" -DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing -Method head

I get back
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           :
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK

When I use CURL, I get 404:
curl "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/blah"
<html>
 <head>
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
  The resource could not be found.<br /><br />
 </body>
</html>

When the resource does exist, Invoke-WebRequest again comes back with 200, and CURL with 302 (found).
What is CURL doing differently from Invoke-WebRequest? I tried Invoke-WebRequest with GET, POST - no change.

If use a URL that actually returns a 404, I get a 404 error from Invoke-WebRequest. For example if I call my own website with a duff URL (Invoke-WebRequest "https://larnu.uk/abc" -DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing -Method head), I a 404 error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

Regarding http redirection, the difference stems from -MaximumRedirection parameter defaults to 5 (meaning it can visit redirected site for a maximum of 5 times) in Invoke-Webrequest. But in curl.exe if do not specify --location parameter, it does not go to the redirected location hence 302 http status code. If you specify --location parameter in curl.exe I think you will get the same results.


The 404 vs. 200 discrepancy:
curl (curl.exe on Windows) vs. PowerShell's web cmdlets, Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod, use different user-agent strings, and many sites modify their behavior based on that string, which explains the different behaviors:

Unfortunately, the user-agent string that PowerShell's web cmdlets use is like that of a full-fledged, interactive browser;[1] e.g., on Windows with version 7.5 of PowerShell (Core) 7:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621; en-US) PowerShell/7.5.0


By contrast, curl uses something like:

curl/8.6.0



With curl, the nonexistent page is reported by the target site as such (status code 404), whereas the browser-like user-agent string used by PowerShell's web cmdlets returns a page meant to be useful for interactive users (and is combined with status code 200).
However, PowerShell's web cmdlets (like curl.exe, with -A / --user-agent) allow you to specify a custom user-agent string, via -UserAgent.
Therefore, you can make your behave like curl as follows:
Invoke-WebRequest -UserAgent curl/8.6.0 https://downloads.sourceforge.net/blah

Note:

-UserAgent curl seems to be enough at least with the URL at hand, though I don't know if that's true for all sites.

You can use https://postman-echo.com/get to determine the user-agent string that is used by a given client; for PowerShell's web cmdlets:
(Invoke-RestMethod https://postman-echo.com/get).headers.'user-agent'




The 302 vs. 200 discrepancy:
As ErkinD39 notes, there's at least one other fundamental difference between curl.exe and PowerShell's web cmdlets: the latter follow redirections by default, up to 5 times, which curl doesn't do.
This explains getting 302 (in curl, no redirections applied) vs. 200 (redirections automatically followed) for a given URL.
The -MaximumRedirection parameter of PowerShell's web cmdlets controls this behavior (which defaults to 5, as noted); -MaximumRedirection 0 disables following redirection.
(curl has the -L (--location) option to request automatic following of redirections, up to 50 times by default; --max-redirs can be used to modify this number.)

[1] Potentially changing this problematic default user-agent string is the subject of GitHub issue #24425.
